# Cannot generate classes from xsd, in Intellij with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have a Java project in IntelliJ with Maven.
The project contains a couple of xsd files and I want to generate java classes from them.
My pom.xml is like this

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>xjc</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <xsdOptions>
            <xsdOption>
              <xsd>/src/main/resources/BulkValuations.xsd</xsd>
            </xsdOption>
            <xsdOption>
              <xsd>/src/main/resources/TPSData.xsd</xsd>
            </xsdOption>
          </xsdOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Then I right click on the module and choose **Maven->Generate Sources and Update Folders**.
Unfortunately no classes are created under target->generated-sources.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: How have you called Maven? What is the output on the console? Some errors? Please try on plain command line.. ?

Comment: Does it work from command line Maven? If so, can you provide a sample project to check?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, cannot reproduce, bud! (i.e. "works like charm", see khmb's comment)

https://github.com/xerx593/soq69358909

> #### Sorry, cannot reproduce!
>
> - Import with IntelliJ, Run (project Context->)Maven-> Generate Sources And Update Folders
> - Run mvn clean install
>
> **Sources are generated into `target/generated/src/main/java`.**
>
> #### Environment
>
> - (latest) IntelliJ Community Edition: 2021.2.2
> - Oracle Winx64 JDK: 17
>
> #### Thanks to
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp for sample xsd!